# Can I extend the error-interface by a method in GO?

Tags: go, struct, interface, extension-methods

I've worked with C# for years so I'm trying to find similarities in GO (I'm quite new to this).

**My goal:**
I would like to extend the interface `error` by a method like `Check()` so I'm able to call `error.Check()` just because of a (in my opinion) better readable code.

**My current state:**
I've already learned how to extend types by methods with this syntax:

```
func (foo T) MyExtension() returnType {
    // return something
}
```

**My problem:**
It looks like this only applies to types but not interfaces. As I've seen so far `error` is an `interface` that's used by many packages to describe a base of their own error-types. I dont want to extend this error-types (from packages) but rather want to extend the interface to cover them all. I couldn't find any syntax for that. As I also don't know the technical term for this (its not `extension-method`) I'm a bit lost in googling around.

**So is there a way to extend the `error` interface by a general method?**

Comment: You cannot dynamically add methods to an interface. If this were possible, types that previously implemented an interface would break at runtime.  You should instead write a function `func Check(err error)`.

Comment: Out of curiosity: what does that `Check()` method do?

Comment: @kostix In the first step just compare the `error`  against `nil` and exit `log.fatal()`. Later I would've planned how to deal with errors in my case the best. For the beginning I was just looking to sum up all occuring errors.

Comment: Summing up: This is a bad idea and luckily it is undoable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't extend `error`, it's a built-in interface type.

You can extend your own interface types by simply adding new methods. This is "dangerous" at first, because implementing interfaces in Go is implicit: there is no declaration of intent. This means if you have a `MyError` interface, some existing types might already implement it and build on this. If you add a new method to it, existing types will most likely not implement it anymore, which will most likely break existing code (unless you add the implementation of that new method).

Judging from the name of your wanted method (`Check()`), best would be to create a utility function:

```
func check(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        panic(err) // Do something
    }
}
```

This "pattern" can be applied with your own interfaces too, it will not disturb existing implementations.

Comment: Yeah I already got that utility function. I would like to not stay on the topic pointed to "errors" but rather to the possibilities of coding in GO. This one answers my question fully. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

I would highly suggest to use casual if statement for error checking.

```
if err != nil {
    log.Printf("Error received - [%v]",err)
    return err
}
```

Because golang doesn't have try catch block familiar to C#.

And if your method Check() will return bool - you will still need to check it against the if statement.

Comment: I wouldn't do so. I would've testet the error against being `nil` inside that `Check()` method and either just return or `log.fatal(..)` or similar. I'm for sure not going to repeat this if-statement all over my code.

Comment: @C4u you need not to return anything. It will do just to check error.

Comment: I haven't said returning `something`. I just said `returning` in the meaning of letting the function run to its end which *returns* even if there's no object that gets returned.

Comment: Also: This question is not ment to be a code-style discussion. I'm very much into coding. I just needed a answer about the possibility to extend interfaces. Everything else is pretty much clear to me. But thanks for the information.